# SQL Server unexpected deadlock

Tags: sql-server, azure

I guess most deadlocks are unexpected, but even looking at the deadlock graph I still find the deadlock unexpected.

- Azure SQL Server.
- Table is very simple. Clustered index on primary key (Id) and no other indexes.
- All updates are on a single row identified by primary key.
- Multiple servers may be updating the table at the same time (usually only two, though).

Deadlock graph image:
[image]

This one deadlocks on page lock. I since added WITH (rowlock) hint, but I still get deadlocks, just on rows instead of pages. I used this example because it was the simplest graph I found.

It seems like the query is running in parallel (Exchange Event) and the different parallel processors are deadlocking each other, but I really wouldn't expect that to happen on something so simple.

Deadlock graph XML:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process228fd04e108" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process228fd04e108" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:2288 " waittime="9103" ownerId="2582803" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.807" XDES="0x22776384df0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="45296" status="suspended" spid="123" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.807" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.803" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.803" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC5B6ACC6" hostpid="16672" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2582803" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x16e67a1e6613ccaa" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="308" sqlhandle="0x02000000035f942bf8a99f27adc04a1730c088079e14a1a90000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process228fd04fc28" taskpriority="0" logused="328" waitresource="PAGE: 5:1:2288 " waittime="6999" ownerId="2582770" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.573" XDES="0x22908ef4960" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="54024" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.573" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.570" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.570" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC5B6ACC6" hostpid="14476" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2582770" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x16e67a1e6613ccaa" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="308" sqlhandle="0x02000000035f942bf8a99f27adc04a1730c088079e14a1a90000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process228f451d088" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="4139" schedulerid="2" kpid="43452" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.573" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-12T12:53:02.570" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.570" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC5B6ACC6" hostpid="14476" loginname="superuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2582770" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x16e67a1e6613ccaa" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="308" sqlhandle="0x02000000035f942bf8a99f27adc04a1730c088079e14a1a90000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="2288" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="9332623d-7c4f-4da3-b054-9be315e6f0a4.dbo.KeyValue" id="lock228c3bed800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594043826176">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process228f451d088" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process228fd04e108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="2288" dbid="5" subresource="FULL" objectname="9332623d-7c4f-4da3-b054-9be315e6f0a4.dbo.KeyValue" id="lock228c3bed800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594043826176">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process228fd04e108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process228fd04fc28" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe2277614e600" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="2" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process228fd04fc28" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process228f451d088" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Edit:

DDL for table:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[KeyValue]    Script Date: 15-06-2020 21:41:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyValue](
    [Id] [varchar](900) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TimestampUtc] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Origin] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KeyValue] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Actual query plan for an edit:

[image]

Another deadlock graph, this one after adding rowlock hint:

[image]

Third graph:
[image]

XML for third graph:

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process28b6db54108" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process28b6db54108" taskpriority="0" logused="396" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594043826176 (36d9edc841fc)" waittime="7137" ownerId="1491320" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:29.570" XDES="0x28b698c9280" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="34896" status="suspended" spid="113" sbid="0" ecid="3" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:29.570" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-15T09:55:29.563" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.563" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC5B6ACC6" hostpid="26324" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1491320" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x01068720fbb54c87" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="338" sqlhandle="0x02000000916f1f032e9e459183cba2f8f5cf5fabfffb31b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process28b6db544e8" taskpriority="0" logused="796" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594043826176 (f8db9e67957b)" waittime="14507" ownerId="1491488" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.380" XDES="0x28b698dedf0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="74440" status="suspended" spid="129" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.380" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.377" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.377" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC552A9B5" hostpid="4176" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1491488" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x01068720fbb54c87" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="338" sqlhandle="0x02000000916f1f032e9e459183cba2f8f5cf5fabfffb31b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process28c66eff848" taskpriority="0" logused="796" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594043826176 (5f732a583b1e)" waittime="7820" ownerId="1491488" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.380" XDES="0x28b69a2fba0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="67308" status="suspended" spid="129" sbid="0" ecid="1" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.380" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.377" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.377" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC552A9B5" hostpid="4176" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1491488" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x01068720fbb54c87" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="338" sqlhandle="0x02000000916f1f032e9e459183cba2f8f5cf5fabfffb31b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process28cf7edd468" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="4232" schedulerid="1" kpid="50744" status="suspended" spid="129" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.380" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-15T09:55:31.377" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.377" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC552A9B5" hostpid="4176" loginname="superuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1491488" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x01068720fbb54c87" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="338" sqlhandle="0x02000000916f1f032e9e459183cba2f8f5cf5fabfffb31b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process28cf7edc8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="4864" schedulerid="1" kpid="59208" status="suspended" spid="113" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-15T09:55:29.570" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-15T09:55:29.563" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.563" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RD501AC5B6ACC6" hostpid="26324" loginname="superuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1491320" currentdb="5" currentdbname="fp-pinfo-prod-db" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x01068720fbb54c87" queryplanhash="0xd91db86605a474c5" line="1" stmtstart="150" stmtend="338" sqlhandle="0x02000000916f1f032e9e459183cba2f8f5cf5fabfffb31b40000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" queryhash="0x0000000000000000" queryplanhash="0x0000000000000000" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(4000))UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 WHERE Id = @p3   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594043826176" dbid="5" objectname="050344b0-8326-468d-9337-48fedc86da64.dbo.KeyValue" indexname="PK_KeyValue" id="lock28c65e13800" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594043826176">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process28cf7edd468" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process28b6db54108" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594043826176" dbid="5" objectname="050344b0-8326-468d-9337-48fedc86da64.dbo.KeyValue" indexname="PK_KeyValue" id="lock28c68183800" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594043826176">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process28cf7edc8c8" mode="X" />
        <owner id="process28cf7edc8c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process28b6db544e8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594043826176" dbid="5" objectname="050344b0-8326-468d-9337-48fedc86da64.dbo.KeyValue" indexname="PK_KeyValue" id="lock28c683a5700" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594043826176">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process28cf7edc8c8" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process28c66eff848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe28b69a26680" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="2" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process28b6db544e8" />
        <owner id="process28c66eff848" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process28cf7edd468" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe28b699e0680" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" waiterType="Coordinator" nodeId="2" tid="0" ownerActivity="sentData" waiterActivity="needMoreData" merging="false" spilling="false" waitingToClose="false">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process28b6db54108" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process28cf7edc8c8" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Can you add the table and index DDL to your question?  And verify no triggers or indexed views.  And the query plans if you can get them.  It's odd to see the exchangeEvent in such a simple query.

Comment: DDL added to question.

Comment: Added execution plan for an update.

Comment: There are no triggers or views on any of our tables, so that's a negative.

Comment: Added another graph with XML.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look tomorrow. Late here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  Simple mistake.  Your PK is `varchar(900)`.  Your UPDATE sends a parameter of type `nvarchar(4000)`.  `nvarchar` has a higher [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than `varchar`, so `varchar` values must be converted to `nvarchar` for comparison.  So what should be a trivial clustered index seek becomes a scan.  And it's the extra cost of the scan that's causing parallel query plans, and the possibility of a deadlock.

To fix this simply use the correct parameter type in .NET or force a conversion in your query.  EG

```
UPDATE KeyValue SET Value = @p0, TimestampUtc = @p1, Origin = @p2 
WHERE Id = cast(@p3 as varchar(900))
```

This will eliminate the parallel plans, the deadlocks, and make this query much, much cheaper.

Comment: You beat me to it, although whether or not the expression is sargable depends on the collation.

Comment: Right, but I believe the parameter expression will use the column's collation, unless a different collation is explicitly specified.  Per the rules here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collation-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#operators-and-collation

Comment: @What I mean is that with a Windows column collation like `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, SQL Server can coerce a index seek even with a Unicode parameter using a range seek expression like `Seek Keys[1]: Start: [tempdb].[dbo].[KeyValue].Id > Scalar Operator([Expr1005]), End: [tempdb].[dbo].[KeyValue].Id < Scalar Operator([Expr1006])`. This won't happen with a legacy SQL collation like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: Great find! I already had this: [Key, Column(TypeName = "varchar(900)")] public string Id { get; set; } - but it was ignored when doing this:                 const string Sql = "UPDATE KeyValue WITH (rowlock) SET Value = {0}, TimestampUtc = {1}, Origin = {2} WHERE Id = {3}";
                await ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(Sql, value, _dateTimeService.UtcNow, Environment.MachineName, id);

Comment: On thing that still surprises me: why does it deadlock when running in parallel? Is that really to be expected?